# Python GTK: make about dialog without logo

Tags: python, gtk

[GNOME Developer Center](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/aboutdialog.py.html.en) website shows About Dialog without an icon. On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS however, it seems that GTK now requires for icon to be present, as without explicitly declaring icon name, that very same example form the website it shows error icon.

[image]

Thus the question: how do I get around this issue ? I want the About dialog for my program only have simple text and no icon/logo.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late to the party but I just stumbled upon your question because I was too searching for an answer to this. What worked for me was this:

```
about = Gtk.AboutDialog() # Create your about dialog object

about.set_logo_icon_name(None)
```

By passing `None` to `set_logo_icon_name` the default window icon set with the `gtk.window_set_default_icon_list()` function will be used. If you haven't specifically specified a default window icon then no icon/logo will be rendered.

Comment: Very nice ! I'll test this out at some point. Thank you for the answer :)